# Remove circles from google maps with gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gmaps.js

I have attached a circle around a marker using the gmaps javascript toolkit.

The ajax call returns the vehicle information, and i run it through a simple parser.

```
  var status_text = "";
  var records = result.split("*");
  var len = records.length - 1; 
  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    var record = records[i].split("|");
    var lll = new google.maps.LatLng(record[4], record[5]);

    var m = current_map.addMarker({
    lat: record[4],
    lng: record[5],
    title: "Vehicle :" + record[2],
    labelStyle: { opacity: 0.50 },
    icon: image
  });


  var c = current_map.drawCircle({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#c3fc49',
    fillOpacity: 0.15,
    radius: eval(record[18]) * 2
  });

  c.bindTo('center', m, 'position');
```

I have a timer setup that needs to remove, and redraw the markers along with the associated circles.

The code is am trying is

```
var VehicleTicketMovementTimer = setInterval(function (){
  var x = current_map.markers.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    current_map.removeMarker(i);
  }
  GetOpenServiceOrders();
  GetLatestVehicleStatus2();
  }, 10000);
```

It appears that the circle just gets more solidly colored in, as if it is not being erased, and if the vehicle is traveling, the marker will move with no trails, but the circle will be drawn at the new location, without erasing the previous circle.

Do i need to break the bindTo from the circle to the marker, or should the marker removal remove the circle that is bound to it?

I am at a loss - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You asked "Do i need to break the bindTo from the circle to the marker?".  If you bind the map property of the marker to the circle as well, it might get removed by the `removeMarker` function

Comment: Why the down vote?   the question was presented with minimal code, tested and is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing all the markers, but i don't see where you are removing the circle from the map, you can remove it by setting it's map to null:

```
var VehicleTicketMovementTimer = setInterval(function () {
    var x = current_map.markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        current_map.removeMarker(i);
    }
    c.setMap(null); //Add this line.
    //if the above does not work, try this:
    c.remove();
    GetOpenServiceOrders();
    GetLatestVehicleStatus2();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: c is not defined
c.setMap(null); //Add this line.
The c (circles) are out of scope for this addition to work.

Comment: Move it to a scope where both your function that draws the circle and the interval can access it...

Comment: Done - moved the c variable to a global scope.  Error was removed.  bubble is not being erased, markers are being erased, but circles are not.

Comment: Edited my answer with another approach, check if it works

Comment: I was going to answer my own question, but after letting the application run, and having more than a single unit (bubble) on the map, the bubbles are not being erased.  If a single bubble is on the screen, it is being erased.   Here is the code i tested it with

     function BuildAndLoadHeat() {
  GetOpenServiceOrders();
  GetLatestVehicleStatus2();

  var VehicleTicketMovementTimer = setInterval(function () {
    current_map.removeMarkers();
    c.setMap(null); 
    GetOpenServiceOrders();
    GetLatestVehicleStatus2();
  }, 10000);
}